# Read excel column wise in Java

Tags: java, excel

I have a requirement to read excel file column wise. And store every column data in different arraylist. Then create a map , column header as a key and arraylist as a value. 
Now there is a stored procedure which have input parameters as excel column header. I have to pass arraylist values as a comma delimeted to every input parameters.

I am using Apache poi to achieve this . I have one solution where I am adding all the cell values into two dimension array and then iterating it column wise . But not happy with this approach.
Below is the code, I am using

```
Object[][] fileArray = new Object[maxRowNo][maxCellNo];
            for (int j = 0; j <= firstSheet.getLastRowNum(); j++) {
                Row row = firstSheet.getRow(j);
                for (int k = 0; k <= row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); k++) {
                    fileArray[k][j] = row.getCell(k).getStringCellValue();
                }

            }
```

Any quick help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Post (add to your question by using [edit]) your existing code and explain what you are not happy about.

Comment: Given the requirements, I personally would use something like `Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap();`

Comment: Hi PM 77-1, Thanks for your attention. I have added piece of code.